# PHPExcel Image include

Tags: image, phpexcel, barcode

I tried hard, just wanna display barcode image in A1 cell. it works well in html. But not in PhpExcel. thanks in advance.

```
$generator = new BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
$wizard = new PHPExcel_Helper_HTML();
$cellText = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($generator->getBarcode('081231723837', $generator::TYPE_CODE_128)) . '">';
$richText = $wizard->toRichTextObject($cellText);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', $richText);
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading about ["in memory" images with PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#add-a-gd-drawing-to-a-worksheet), rather tan trying to assume that everything in the world is just html markup

Comment: Though thanks for highlighting a bug with the html writer; html markup in a rich text object should be escaped to prevent it being displayed as html

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i got answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Try whith:

> https://github.com/davidscotttufts/php-barcode

### generating barcode.png

```php
    $filepath = 'barcode.png';
    $text = '1234567890123';
    $size = "80";
    $orientation = "horizontal";
    $code_type = "code128";
    $print = "true";
    $sizefactor = "0.8";
    barcode( $filepath,$text, $size, $orientation, $code_type, $print, $sizefactor );
```

### Report:

```php
    $imgBarcode = imagecreatefrompng('bar_code.png');
    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
    $objDrawing->setDescription('barcode');
    $objDrawing->setImageResource($imgBarcode);
    $objDrawing->setHeight(100);
    $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```